# When scaling back to "original" scale after shrinking, it defaults to 1,1,1, which isn't what I want

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale

The game object I'm scaling is simple. It shows the thrust for the ship being used (this last for 2 seconds as the bar decreases). Then for 3 seconds, the object scales back up to almost exactly where it was, but it needs to be exact or over time the object will not look correct after several uses (the scaling would get exponentially worse, and we know this is no good). I've researched this for the past hour or 2 with no avail in anything I try. This is the closest thing I've been able to mash up.

Overall problem: It needs to be EXACTLY 5 every time it scales back. I realize if I take off the last else if statement it works (poorly), but no matter what number I put in for the X it doesn't always scale to the exact same number, which is a problem, and why I need to return it's original scale.

tl;dr My object's X value scales from 5 to near 0, when trying to return it to its original scale (of 5) it scales up to near 5 then goes to 1,1,1.

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShipPlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

 [Header ("Camera(s)")]
 public Camera CameraObject;

 [Header ("Float(s)")]
 public float fireRate = 0.3f;
 public float fireTimer = 0.0f;
 public float moveSpeedX = 12.0f;
 public float moveSpeedY = 8.0f;

//counts from 0 to 5, so I can use the thrust again (starts at 5 so they can use it initially, this resets to 0 every time they press T and its been over 5 seconds)    
    public float thrusterTimer = 5.0f;

//the rate at which I can thrust, the lower the number the more often you can use it     
    public float thrusterRate = 5.0f;

//how long the player is actually thrusting  
    public float thrusterActive = 2.0f;


 private Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;

//supposed to be the original scale i've made for the game object???     
    private Vector3 originalScale; //(also have tried adding = Vector3.zero;)


 [Header ("Script(s)")]
 public Projectile bullet;
 public HUD hudScript;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
 
  updatePosition ();

  updateFiring ();

  updateThrust ();

//calling the method when I push "t" for thrust
  updateThrusterBar ();

 }

//Skipping a bunch of unneeded code
  ........................................
  
//Gets called once I press "T"
  public void updateThrusterBar () {

//Supposed to be the original scale???
  originalScale = transform.lossyScale;

//When I press "T" the bar shrinks showing the player is using their thrust
  if (thrusterActive > thrusterTimer) {

   hudScript.thrustBar.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (-0.04187f, 0, 0);

//Fills the thrust back up so they can see when its full
  } else if (thrusterTimer < thrusterRate) {

   hudScript.thrustBar.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (0.029f, 0, 0);

//(Doesn't work): Logically, if the X scale isn't 5, then go back to your original scale i've made for you, which in the game is (5,0.3,1)
//What happens: defaults to (1,1,1) in the game, which is a square...
  } else if (hudScript.thrustBar.transform.localScale.x != 5.0f) {
  
   hudScript.thrustBar.transform.localScale = originalScale;
  
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using transform.lossyScale?

Comment: Also, You say that you are calling the function when you press T, but your code doesn't reflect that